# How do I create date in register form

Tags: laravel

How do I create date of birth or date in register form?  I am trying to make Register form. How can I do this?
[Output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4NRx.png)

In user models:

```
public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('project.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d') : null;
    }
```

In Blade files:

```
<div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="material-icons">event</i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <input name="date_of_birth" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ trans ('global.date_of_birth') }}..." value="{{ old('date_of_birth' }} " required autocomplete="name" autofocus> config('project.date_format')
    </div>
    @error('date_of_birth')
        <div class="error" for="date_of_birth">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: what's the format in `project.date_format` ? and what value do you get in `$value`?

Comment: <?php

return [
    'date_format'            => 'd/m/Y',
    'time_format'            => 'H:i:s',
    'datetime_format'        => 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
    'moment_date_format'     => 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    'moment_time_format'     => 'HH:mm:ss',
    'moment_datetime_format' => 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
    'supported_languages'    => [
        [
            'title'      => 'ພາສາລາວ',
            'short_code' => 'la',
        ],
        [
            'title'      => 'English',
            'short_code' => 'en',
        ],
    ],
    'registered_user_role' => 'User',
];